# How to turn on ECI and its value in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, qr-code

So i m using qr library : angularx-qrcode , which has this link: https://openbase.com/js/angularx-qrcode/documentation

Note that i have angular 11

I included it in my appmodule and my project and filled it with some data (qrInfo).

```
this.qrData = 'all my data for qr'
this.qrInfo = JSON.stringify(this.qrData)
```

In my html i write the following:

```
        <qrcode [qrdata]="qrInfo" [width]="150" [elementType]="Binary" [version]="15" [allowEmptyString]="true"
            [errorCorrectionLevel]="'M'">
        </qrcode>
```

I am trying to set the following rules to my qr : Version 15, Mode Byte, Error Correction Level M, ECI, set ECI value to 4 , characters : ISO-8859-2.

The QR does get read with my app on the phone but it doesnt meet the specific requerments

In the documentation i dont find any others that i have and tried to do it anyways... Is there any better Angular library for qr or how do i set this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the lib [angularx-qrcode](https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode), which is based on node-qrcode - which in turn has no full ECI implementation yet.

A lot of the available angular QR Code libs are based on node-qrcode, so there is only a very small chance, that you find one with ECI configuration implemented.

Again from the node-qrcode libs website:

> Most QR Code readers, however, are able to recognize multibyte characters even without ECI.

So it  might be possible for your use case, to create a qrcode which is readable by your lib and/or device.

You can try a lot of different configurations on
[angularx-qrcode Demo Page](https://cordobo.github.io/angularx-qrcode/)